# How to find all clusters of forest on map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine

How to find all clusters of forest on map ?
I have simple class cell like (Type is enum {RIVER, FOREST,GRASS,HILL}

```
class Cell{
   public:
     Type type;
     int x;
     int y
};
```

and map like `vector<Cell> grid`. Can anyone suggest me algorithm to create `list<list<Cell>> clusters` where list contains FOREST cells in same cluster (cluster are set of connected cells - connection can be in eight direction:up,down,left,right,up_right,up_left,down_left,down_right)? I need to find all clusters of forest on map and put every single cluster in `list<Cell>`.

Comment: Define "cluster". Is it any connected set of FOREST cells? Do diagonals count?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What are you using it for and how is a cluster defined? Is a cluster simply all elements of type forest that are adjacent to another element of type forest, or something else?

Comment: Look up the [union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).  Using path compression, you can just walk through the structure afterwards and create a list for each root, adding your cells to the appropriate list as you go.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is rather simple and it actually doesn't even depend on the exact definition of what a cluster is. Say you have a predicate `cluster(f0, f1)` which yields `true` if `f0` and `f1` are in the same cluster. All you need to do is to run though the `grid` and find a forest. If a cell `f` is a forest, you check if `cluster(f, other)` for each known forest. If `cluster(f, other)` yields `true` you add `f` to the cluster of `other`. You continue to check other known forests in other clusters: when you find another cell `c` in another cluster for `cluster(f, c)` also yields `true`, you merge (`std::list<Cell>::spice()`) the two clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I had put this as a comment, but may as well answer:

> Look up the union-find algorithm. Using path compression, you can just
>   walk through the structure afterwards and create a list for each root,
>   adding your cells to the appropriate list as you go.

Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

For all your cells, perform a union with the cell above and to the left.  If you want diagonals to join, then also include the top-left and top-right diagonal).

Use the path-compression version of union-find so that all nodes in a cluster point to a single root.  Then all you have to do is walk through your structure (after doing all the unions) and add nodes as you go.  Pseudo(ish)code:

```
foreach node
    Find(node)               // this ensures path compression

    if not clusters.hasList(node.root)
        clusters.createList(node.root)
    end

    list <- clusters.getList(node.root)
    list.append(node)
end
```

The above assumes that if a node is a root, then `node.root` points to `node`.